# Qubes OS fails to install from USB drive

Tags: linux, installation

I'm trying to install Qubes, but absolutely nothing seems to go right.

1. I start the installation from a USB key on which I dd'd : Qubes-R3.1-rc1-x86_64-DVD.iso
2. X fails to start, so it runs the installer from the command line.
3. It asks me for the Installation source, but why since I already booted this installer from a USB stick on which I put the .iso? So I copy the .iso to a second USB key so I can specify the installer is the exact same iso file that runs it.
4. The installation starts, but it fails very quickly. Here is the short output:

   ```
   Progress   
   Setting up the installation environment. 
   Creating biosboot on /dev/nvme0n1p5. 
   Creating luks on /dev/nvme0n1p7
   (anaconda : 1184): Gdk-ERROR ** : error : XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment. Pane is dead.
   ```
5. main is frozen from now on. I can go to log-storage; the last line is:

   ```
   INFO kernel: [408.762974] traps : anaconda[1410] trap int3 ip:7f339671f4e9 sp:7f3380a0a8e0 error:0
   ```

Here is a [description of my computer](http://pcpartpicker.com/p/pdtkMp).

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Had a similar experience with the USB install. Almost gave up but then tried DVD install (with the same ISO over an external DVD drive). Was slow to boot up, but installed fine. Still have no idea why. Never had any problem installing any other distro over USB.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) live USB creator tool to make a Qubes live USB. You can run Rufus in Windows either by installing it in Windows or by running the Rufus Portable version. Be sure to select *DD Image* mode. You need to do that after selecting the Qubes iso image as shown in the screenshot and in the [installation guide](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/installation-guide/).

[image: Rufus]

The Qubes installer loads the Xen hypervisor right at the beginning, so chances are high that if you can see the installer's graphical screen, Qubes will work on your system.

Comment: I don't understand, did you read my post ? I already put the installer iso on a USB that I boot, the problem is that once I choose "Install Qubes" it says X server failed to start and the rest of what I said.

Comment: If the Qubes installer's graphical screen doesn't start when you are using a Qubes live USB made with the `dd` method, you're stuck more or less permanently since the Qubes OS USB installer is still in alpha. To ameliorate this ironic situation, Qubes has provided an alternate method to `dd` of making a Qubes live USB using Rufus. Admittedly I'm trying to lead a horse to water as you more or less suggested. If you don't want to drink it that's cool, but what harm could it do to have a lick? Qubes is a fantastic idea that might be worth some pain.

Comment: i didn't realize you were talking about the live USB, what I did is put the `Qubes-R3.1-rc1-x86_64-DVD.iso` installer onto a USB using `dd` it is booting fine except the installation process fails. I'm downloading the live USB to see if I manage to start the live version of Qubes

Comment: @ChiseledAbs - please see the [relevant Qubes issue](https://github.com/QubesOS/qubes-issues/issues/2051) from their tracker.